# XML : Get an array of string from text cut by element

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I need to get an array of string from a text in a node which is itself cut by an other element in a xml file. I work in C with the libxml2 library.

Exemple :
`<option>some text <middletag />other text</option>`

I tried with `xmlNodeGetContent(xmlnode);` but I only get a string like `"some text other text"`.

The question is : Is it possible to get an array of string which, with this exemple, would be `{"some text ", "other text"}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution, and I have to say I feel ashamed because it took me too much time to find it.

It's simple, I take this exemple again :

```
<option>some text <middletag />other text</option>
```

With this you can have a `xmlnode *` on the `<option>` node. We can find the part `some text <middletag />other text` with a loop on the list `xmlnode->children`. We just have to look for the nodes with the type `XML_TEXT_NODE` and get the content.

Code :

```
xmlNode *node = option_node->children;
for (; node; node = node->next){
    if (node->type == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        printf("%s\n", node->content);
    }
}
```

Result :

```
some text
other text
```

Now, with malloc / realloc, we can save it in an array.